# Checkbox next to collapsable details summary in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to place a checkbox next to the expandable summary of a details element which is inside a `ng-repeat`.

It all looks fine initially, but when I click on the expand arrow, the checkbox gets places inside the summary instead of next to the arrow. The checkbox must be inside the `ng-repeat` because I need the `$index` in my checkbox `ng-click` function:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in ctrl.array track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" style="display: inline-block"
               ng-model="ctrl.checked[$index]" ng-click="ctrl.setSelected($index)">
        <details style="display: inline-block">
            <summary>Display something (element {{$index + 1}})</summary>
            <iframe></iframe>
        </details>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is the styling with "display: inline-block". When I remove it, the problem does not occur anymore. However, I want the checkbox to be placed left to the summary arrow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just have to use

```
style="float: left"
```

for the input element. That's it. No further styling of the details element needed.